# Selenium: Is it possible to change Firefox config settings without starting a new driver?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using Selenium and I want to change the settings in Firefox the same way a person would by going into about:config and changing the values. All of the documentation I've seen shows that settings are changed by setting the preferences through the profile and to use that profile when starting a driver. I want to avoid closing and loading a new driver every time I want to change the settings. Is this possible and if so how is it done? I'm using C# where the FirefoxDriver.Profile property is protected and can't be accessed externally.

Comment: These used to be in various user profile sqlite DBs... Has this changed?

Comment: When you change values in about:config, do the values take effect straight away or require a restart?

Comment: If I go into about:config and change the values myself, there are no issues. However, I don't know how to get Selenium to change the configuration settings. Based on documentation I've read online, the way to set those values would be to do it using a profile, and load profile when starting up a new Firefox driver. I haven't found a way to simply change those settings using Selenium, like a user would by going into about:config.

Comment: You must have misunderstood what I was asking. When you change a value in the about:config, does that change take effect immediately or do you have to restart Firefox for that change to take effect? If I say, change the download location using about:config, do I need to restart my Firefox for it to take effect?

Comment: Yeah, at least for the settings I've changed, I've not had to restart Firefox before they take effect.